# How to insert date this year i.e. 30/7/CurrentYear

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to write a script that will insert the month and date consistently but use the current year. I have tried this:

```
DECLARE @startDateVar DATETIME = '31/7/'+year(getdate())
```

But it doesn't work with error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '31/7/' to data type int.

Ideally I can capture the current year and pass it to the constructor for the `DATETIME` variable. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: DECLARE @startDateVar DATETIME= CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4)) + '0731';
SELECT @startDateVar;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the proper date-format `YYYY-MM-DD` to avoid ambiguity, and use `CONCAT()` to join the strings together (as `YEAR()` returns an int, you need to either use `CONCAT()` to concatenate it, or cast it to a string before you can add it to your other string).

```sql
DECLARE @startDateVar DATETIME = CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()), '-07-31')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DATEFROMPARTS`:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),7,31);
```

Comment: One would assume that the OP is using a supported version of SQL Server too, of course @DavidG (seeing as 2008 is literally about lose support, so people *should* be migrating off it). If Microsoft can't be expected to support old versions of SQL Server, then those answering questions here can't really be expected to be; unless the Op is specific on that they are using an unsupported version. but then we know that the OP is using 11 year old technology. :)

Comment: @BigJolene . . . This is the right answer and you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT GETDATE()` will return as `2019-05-16 08:35:03.257`, so if you are assign the value in `yyyy-mm-dd` format it will accept.

So using `CONCAT()` with the `yyyy-mm-dd` format helps:

```
DECLARE @startDateVar DATETIME = CONCAT(year(getdate()), '-07-31')
SELECT @startDateVar
```

the output will be `2019-07-31 00:00:00.000`